# Aspect oriented programming library for C# (compact framework 3.5)

Tags: c#, compact-framework, aop

Any suggestions for C# aspect oriented programming libraries with support for compact framework version 3.5? It seems that PostSharp supports it, but are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Sounds like a good question for: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Alternatives? http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/alternatives but I have no idea if they support CF. Since most of the alternatives (.NET) use proxies/interception I wouldn't think they would support CF.

PostSharp by SharpCrafters. http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/download

It does support CF 3.5. If you've used Postsharp for regular .NET (if you had, you probably wouldnt be asking this question) you'll see it does have differences.

http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/2.0/##PostSharp.chm/html/695ec9f3-577a-4175-8cba-c00d0cb6e47c.htm

> Because Silverlight or Compact Framework projects are not linked to
>   the normal .NET Frameworks (the public key of mscorlib and even the
>   name of other system assemblies differ), assemblies generated from
>   these projects cannot be loaded into the CLR.
>
> This has a number of direct consequences:
>
> ```
> *Aspects are not instantiated at build time by PostSharp.
> *Therefore, aspects are not serialized.
> *Compile-time semantics like CompileTimeValidate,
> ```
>
> CompileTimeInitialize, IAspectBuildSemantics or IAspectProvider, are
>   not supported.